# How can I make the IF statements print in the webpage?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want the result for my IF statement to be visible in the website itself not in the console. How can I do it?

```
let price = 100;
let discount = false;
let discountAmount = 30;
let country = "Syria";

if (discount === true) {
    price -= discountAmount;
} else if (country === "Egypt") {
    price -= 40;
} else if (country === "Syria") {
    price -= 50;
} else {
    price -= 10;
}

console.log(price);
```

Comment: You could use `alert`, but it depends.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: The same way you display any other variable in the web page. The `if` is irrelevant.